# How does polars handle modulus of negative numbers

Tags: python, python-polars

I see that polars has a modulus operator but it seems to work different than I expect, in this example code:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

x = 2.1
df = pl.DataFrame({'x':x})

print(x % 2) # Prints 0.1
print(np.mod(x,2)) # Prints 0.1
print(df.select(pl.col('x').mod(2))) # Prints 0.1

x = -.1
df = pl.DataFrame({'x':x})

print(x % 2) # Prints 1.9
print(np.mod(x,2)) # Prints 1.9
print(df.select(pl.col('x').mod(2))) #Prints -0.1
```

You can see that I get the same answer from %, numpy and polars when I start from a positive number, but a different answer when starting from a negative.  Is there a way to force polars to return the positive version matched to numpy?

Comment: Just add `2` if the modulo results in a negative value?

Comment: Tinkering a bit more I find I can get the result I want by changing the last line to: print(df.select(np.mod(pl.col('x'),2)))

Comment: Just to be clear, you "fixed" the issue with negatives in polars by switch to the numpy modulus call, right? Not that this is a bad choice, just want to be clear for the person with the same question who finds this post in the future.

Comment: That's right, I guess I'm still unclear if the polars answer is different than the numpy result intentionally, or if I'm making a mistake in how I call it.  But for noting for the future, I think if you want the numpy result I was realizing I can use numpy within the call

Comment: Polars ultimately dispatches to Rust’s `%` operator, which is the remainder operator, _not_ the modulo operator. Meanwhile in python, `%` is the modulo operator. In Rust, modulo can be obtained with `rem_euclid` but it doesn't look like this is made available in Python Polars.

Comment: nice find. I made a bug report. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10570

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in the next version 0.20.7

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10570#event-11658258867